# How to increase error limit in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

When building an application in Visual Studio. It shows the following error when exceeding the error count

```
    fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

Is there a way to increase the error limit?

Comment: just curious, why would you want to do that?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible or not, but may I ask you about your motivation? Do you get more than 100 *meaningful* error messages?

Comment: Let's say I want to find all the functions that are declared in a header and used in a source file. That header may include thousands of other headers in turn. If I disable inclusion of that header the compilation will fail with C1003. The bad part of that is that the failure will occur in a header down the inclusion hierarchy, so that I will never find out which functions were used in my source file.

Comment: I'd suggest fixing these 100 first... short TODO lists are happy TODO lists!

Comment: @Oleksii Skidan, then maybe the question you should be asking is "how do I list the functions declared in a header and used by my program".

Comment: @avakar Nope. The approach I use is pretty normal and it's fast. And I don't need to list all the functions that my program uses. I need to list only those that are declared in a specific subset of headers. And the situation is not that simple as you might think. These functions violate ODF greatly, because there's another library that provides exact the same functions.

Comment: @Okeksii: it's such a "normal and fast" approach that the compiler doesn't support it? GCC does the same thing. The problem is that every time it encounters an error, the compiler has to *guess* at what was probably meant, in order to keep compiling. If it has to keep guessing, it ends up compiling completely made-up code, and then you get errors that have nothing to do with your actual code. That is why it stops after a certain number of errors. As @avakar said, you're going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Here is a reason for this: I want to upgrade a large project to UNICODE. I have been fixing errors for 50 hours at this point, and I want to know if there is any hope of finishing. All the errors are meaningful, and I just need to gauge the scope.

Comment: @Knyphe: tricky. I don't know of a way to do it. If I were you, I'd try to find another way to gauge the amount of work ahead of you. Can you search for potentially broken code? or compile each .cpp file in isolation, so you get a number of smaller error lists, which you can manually (or with a script) combine together

Comment: @Knyphe: Even if you were to be able to expand the displayed error count, it would be useless for many reasons previously mentioned. As I've found that fixing one thing will eliminate many errors.

Comment: I have another reason to need it: Boost.  It's highly templated, so in some cases it produces >100 error messages for the same error, only the _last_ of which is really useful; that one tells you which source line had the error.  The rest are just "see declaration of..." all the way down the template stack.

Comment: If you aren't in a position to fix the one or two things causing so many errors, and you want to address something else first, then you may want to display more at once. At least this is the state I'm in now (leading me here).

Comment: I have a similar situation as described by Knyphe.  the main difference is this is related to a production database of which we have close to 2 dozen copies..  I have been addressing errors but have no idea due to the non-changing error count of how much impact I have had much less of how much time I am looking at spending on this.

Comment: I missed that at the bottom of the list there is a status line telling me there are over 4000 errors remaining.    so that's something..   &%^@

Comment: It would definitely be useful to be able to see more than 100 errors. For example, when you're porting a large project and there's lots of errors to clean up it lets you know how far you still have to go. The IntelliJ suite of IDEs includes this option, so its a pity that Visual Studio doesn't.

Answer (score 29):

This limitation is hardcoded. Here is the post from the MSFT employee in the `microsoft.public.vsnet.general` group dated 2006 (look for 'Fatal Error C1003'):

> Hi,
>
> Unfortunately this 100 limitation is
>   hard coded and cannot be changed. It's
>   just inpractical to keep all errors
>   information around since one error may
>   cause other several errors.
>
> I hope you understand the rational
>   behind this design by our product
>   team.  However, if you still have
>   concerns about this, please feel free
>   to submit  your feedback at
>   http://connect.microsoft.com/Main/content/content.aspx?ContentID=2220
>   which  is monitored by our product
>   team. Thank you for your
>   understanding.
>
> Sincerely, Walter Wang
>   (waw...@online.microsoft.com, remove
>   'online.')  Microsoft Online Community
>   Support"

Answer (score 7):

I don't think so. VS basically reports all errors it encounters during compilations. There might be some erroneous parts of the code that make the compiler getting caught in an infinite "error" loop.

The limit was implemented to avoid that. In most cases the 100 errors you get are just the same error reported over and over again. What would be the sense in increasing the number of repetitions?

Maybe you can post the code snippet where the error occurs first, so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that it is a hard-coded limit, so no.

As others have commented, it's difficult to understand what you want to achieve by this.

At the end of the day, you'll have to fix them all, so get stuck in and start fixing them.  Eventually, you'll get below 100, and you can start counting them.

It is not normally valuable to report the actual number of errors when this occurs.  Most of the time, when you get C1003, it's actually only a few *real* errors, leading to a massive chain of other errors.

(e.g.)

- If there is an error in a .h file, that error will be reported in every .cpp file that `#includes` it.
- If there is an error that prevents any kind of identifier being defined (e.g. a class, variable, method name), then every time you try to use it later on, an error will be reported.

Comment: @ Paul Butcher Eg if you have 3 projects and two depend on a class library then the two can be throwing a zillion errors due to the library but you can't get to the library errors due to the limit. That's where I am right now and it's a pain. Even if you only compile the library, the other two projects' errors get in the way.

Answer (score 4):

Workaround to **reduce** number of reported errors:

- rename cl.exe to cl-orig.exe
- roll your own cl.exe that launches cl-orig.exe, capturing its stdout / stderr
- parse stderr, looking for error messages and counting them
- breaks after first n errors

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a project like this: sometimes Visual Studio decides there is a lot to do, emits 100 really irrelevant messages about other parts of the solution and aborts the build because it reached the message limit without working on the project I'm interested on.

The workaround we have found is to use msbuild to build the solution from a command prompt: the [Use MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-using-msbuild?view=vs-2019) walkthrough outlines the steps. msbuild outputs all messages to the console and once the build completes we can work and debug again in Visual Studio. Not ideal, but it lets us complete the task at hand.