# How to debug problems with The Entity Data Model Designer (Entity Framework)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have inhereted some project which uses Entity Framework in a way which makes it hard to make there any changes. It uses **QueryViews** for almost all tables (cca 50 tables) and of course stored procedures. Now I have to change there quite a lot of things ... rename tables, add tables, change columns etc.

When I tried to use the **"Update Model from database ..."**  wizard, than after the update (where I added/removed the tables and let refresh the others using the wizard) from the database the Entity Data Model Designer rendering stops working ... there is just blank window with the text **"The Entity Data Model Designer is unable to display the file you requested.**"

So I tried different approaches (like manually editing the **edmx** file), but the problem remains. The editor shows only the "The Entity Data Model Designer is unable to display the file you requested."

The mapping using QueryViews makes it probably more complicated. It is well known that the designer can not work with the QueryViews properly (one can not edit them using the designer) and the Entity framework engine even does not recognize that the columns from CSDL are mapped using the QueryViews and complains on each and every column (which is mapped using QueryView) that "**Error 11009: Property 'XXX' is not mapped.**" I see exactly 100 errors like this. Maybe somewhere after the 100th error, there is some hint (in the form of other errors) how to fix the issue with Designer, but I don't know how to see them. The 100 limit is most likely hardcoded in VS2010 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880936/how-to-increase-error-limit-in-visual-studio).

Btw. the code (classes for entities etc.) is generated without problems.

So, the question is:**Is there a way how to see some log or something, where would be noted why the Entity framework Data Model Designer is not able to render anything?**

**Or is there at least some way how to see the rest of the errors (besides the 100 errors)?**

**Or does anybody know the ideal way of dealing with updating schema in EF besides using the wizard?**

Comment: You could try generating the model using EdmGen - it is a bit cumbersome but will show you all the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add new EDMX and right click >> open with >> XML editor, then you can see a complete set in an empty model definition in EDMX. So you can compare the two EDMX and check notice which part of the EDMX is missing.

[Here is the error link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee524052.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have just do all the changes manually by ***editing the xml***. However, I used the model designer (the GUI integrated in VS for EF) for creating the whole CSDL layer. So my approach was to carefully choose tables in the correct order and add them one by one in the multiple iterations of the following steps:

1. Use the model designer to create the csdl layer for the chosen table including all relations with already existing table. This at least ensured that the designer was usable later on and it saves the manual writing of the CSDL objetcs.
2. Write the SSDL layer, which should reflect the DB table.
3. Write the mapping layer (in my case using the QueryViews).
4. Try to compile and resolve all compile errors.
5. Repeat for next table (or more tables if you find it easier).

I hope this will help somebody.