# All errors shown by the compiler (Maximum number of errors has been exceeded)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vb6

We've been asked to migrate a project from vb6 to vb.net. We used the conversion wizard from visual studio 2008 and as we expected lots of errors came along.

I know that there is a hardcoded limit of errors shown by the compiler (100 i guess).
But we're on a tight schedule and we'd need all the errors so we could give an estimate on how much time we'd take for this project to be converted.

One option would be fixing the errors that we have now. But there's a high probability that more errors would be generated and as i said, we have to give an estimate as soon as possible...

Is there a way for me to get a list of all errors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880936/how-to-increase-error-limit-in-visual-studio

Comment: If you think that migrating from VB (non-.NET) to VB.NET is *only* about fixing the errors the compiler complains about, then you're going to have a steep learning curve, late in the project. I would urge you to talk to someone that has done such a migration already and get some help with the estimation. And no, you can't get all those errors without starting to fix them. The limit is fixed.

Comment: I know that there's more than fixing errors on migrating projects. It's something i've already talked with the rest of the team. We could try to fix those errors but there's runtime errors, not treated exceptions, some technologies may not work with vs2008, missing references, new methods, and etc etc. It's just that if we had all the errors, we could estimate. (not 100% accurate but <insert that it's something meme here>)

Comment: A single missing assembly reference could generate 100+ compiler errors, and could be solved in 15 seconds. It's not a good method to estimate work TBD.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to get all of the errors that would be generated by the compilation.  As you noted the error limit is a hard coded value in the compiler.  Once that limit is reached the compiler will cease emitting error messages.

Even if you could get all of the error messages I would say it's not the best way to judge the amount of time it will take you to port from VB6 to VB.Net.  They are very different environments (VB6 being essentially an STA COM environment while VB.Net is just another CLR language) and these differences can manifest in unexpected ways.  The number of errors will give you an estimate of how long it will take to compile but not how long until the app is actually working again