# "maximum number of errors has been exceeded" but no errors nor warnings listed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm facing a very odd situation. I'm trying to rebuild a legacy asp.net web site that targets .net 4.5 version and when I try to rebuild, I get the "maximum number of errors has been exceeded". When I look into the error list window, I see no other errors nor warning.

Any ideas of what could possibly be causing this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the Output window?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this is a limitation imposed by the compiler. Verified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30041

You can see 100 errors at a time. You will have to resolve some to see the others. If you only see the max errors error in the error list, then I suggest using the output window and show output from Build to locate what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this problem is to build the solution from a command prompt using msbuild. Some more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55941846/1623757)

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the Error List is filtered. Make sure that "Errors" is selected

[image: Error List Filters]

Comment: I checked and the error list is checked. Still the only error that shows is the same "maximum number of errors has been exceeded"

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to your question?