# In Visual Studio Code, how can I bypass the error limit? "Error limit exceeded"

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code with the Microsoft C/C++ plugin for C coding.

However, in some large files, which has a lot of errors due to un-resolved headers, it does not show code errors after a limit. I get this error:

Error limit exceeded, 286 error(s) not reported.C/C++

I can not include all the headers due to the size of the project.

Is there anyway to bypass this limit?

Comment: Have you considered fixing the errors

Comment: This is a dup: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880936/how-to-increase-error-limit-in-visual-studio" However, it's like 10 years old so maybe it has changed since then

Comment: Usually you start by chopping down how many errors there are in the first place. This is basically saying "Your code is so busted I can't even." so start by commenting out parts that cause the most problems and at least get it to compile first.

Comment: How would it help to see *all* errors at once? A good strategy is to fix the first error. Then repeat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase error limit in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880936/how-to-increase-error-limit-in-visual-studio)

Comment: How will you be able to compile the whole program if you do not include the required headers

Comment: I do not import the whole program in Visual Studio as its quite large. I only import a component. So, I do not need to compile it in Visual Studio, just want to see errors while adding new code.